# Android EditText - Not able to enter value

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm a newbie in Android development. Recently, I have been facing a problem in the `EditTexts` used in my app which I'm currently running in Emulator. On clicking the `EditText` it receives focus, but on typing something I m unable to enter values.

Any help would be appreciable.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/amt"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:inputType="number" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u see the cursor??

Comment: setting inputType="number" only allows numbers to be entered. Are you able to do that?

Comment: I think your code is proper, so i'll suggest try it on your device, may it works.

Comment: you try to enter values with your PC  keyboard ?

Comment: please use only emulator's keyboard - don't use physical keyboard's numpade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line from xml file

```
android:inputType="number"
```

and if you want to enter anything then set input type of EditText

```
 android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: Can  you please explain how making the input type "textNoSuggestions" will allow us to type in edit Text @Piyush Guptha

Answer (score 0):

delete this line `android:inputType="number"` and it should work now